# Strech QGraphicsView horizontally

Tags: qt, qt4, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

How to add horizontal stretch feature to a QGraphicsView? Please help

Comment: You are going to provide more detail: stretch the contents or the widget?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to stretch the content of a graphics view: [`QGraphicsView::scale()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html#scale)

```
myGraphicsView->scale(stretch, 1);
```